# Perl regex - Having the delimiter as part of the string itself

Tags: regex, perl

I have a long string in the format

```
id1:2014-08-05 11:24;Does this work?,id2:2014-08-04 13:22; Does this work,too?,id3:2014-07-25 16:56 ...
```

I am trying to extract the 'date' and 'comment' part out of this, based on the id, which is the input. 
  For example, if the input is id2, I'd want the comment as 'Does this work, too?' and date as '2014-08-04 13:22'. Here is the regex I have so far.

```
if($string =~ m/\b$id:(.*?);(.*,?)/){
  my $date = $1;
  my $comment = substr($2,0,-1); #to remove the last ,
}
```

Now since there is a ',' as part of the string itself, my regex treats it as a delimiter and just returns 'Does this work' as the comment, leaving out the ',too?' part.
   Any help would really help as to how to handle when my string has the delimiter within itself.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is to form a hash out of the string. If you start by splitting the string on any comma that's immediately followed by some alphanumeric characters and a colon then the commas within the comments will be ignored and most of your work is done.

Then just use a regex to divide each split into three chunks: the ID, the date/time, and the comment, and put them into a hash. After that you can get the date/time for an ID as `$data{id1}[0]` and the comment as `$data{id1}[1]`

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'id1:2014-08-05 11:24;Does this work?,id2:2014-08-04 13:22; Does this work,too?,id3:2014-07-25 16:56 ...';

my %data;
for (split /,(?=\w+:)/, $s) {
  my @fields = /([^:]+):([^;]+);(.+)/g;
  $data{$1} = [ $2, $3 ];
}

print $data{id2}[1], "\n";
```

**output**

```
 Does this work,too?
```

Comment: +1, looks good. You could be even more specific with the `split` and use something like `/,(?=id\d+:)/`.

Comment: @TomFenech: I doubt if the *real* IDs start with `id`!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "id1:2014-08-05 11:24;Does this work?,id2:2014-08-04 13:22; Does this work,too?,id3:2014-07-25 16:56; bla";
$id = "id2";
# I need comma to set the end of the last "record"
$str = $str . ",";
if ($str =~ /$id:([\d\-\: ]+);([ \w\?\,]+)\,/) {
   print "date = $1\n";
   print "comment = $2\n";
}
```